# Get files from ftp and show files directory path in console - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, ftp

I'm new to node.js and trying to get files from FTP with [ftp module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) and then I want to show files directory path in console. When I run server with npm start, I get all files(thats nice) but console returns empty array. If I run server again with npm start, console show every path(awesome), but not for new files. I have tried to solve my problem with callbacks and setTimeout with no result :C

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var c = new Client();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = path.join(__dirname, '../excelTime/');
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

const connectionProperties = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user_geek',
  port: '21'
}
```

**Get files from ftp**

```
const getFilesFromFTP = () => {
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.list('./', function(err, list) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          const name = list[i].name;
          c.get('/' + name, function(err, stream) {
            if (err) console.dir(err);
            if(!err) {
              stream.once('close', function() { c.end();  });
              stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./excelTime/' + name, {flags: 'w'}));
           }
          });
        }).call(this, i);
      }
      c.end();
    });
  });

  c.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
  c.connect(connectionProperties);
}
```

**Get file path**

```
const checkFolder = () => {
  let promises = files.map(file => path.join(dir, file));
  Promise.all(promises).then(console.log);
}
```

**Call**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  checkFolder();
}, 3000);

getFilesFromFTP();
```

Comment: `files` is undefined in your example and you never call `getFilesFromFTP`. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin I am sorry. Just edited post